# React native redux not updating props properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a simple react native component that when I click a button it triggers an action and I want it to update the props from the same component.

I am doing something like this:

component.js

```
class TypeButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                name = "Type"
                render = {this.customRender.bind(this)}
                onPress = {this.onPress.bind(this)}
                size={60}
            />
        )
    }

    onPress() {
        let type = this.props.type == FREE ? PAID : FREE;

        this.props.userInputAction({
            type : type
        });
    }

    customRender() {
        return (
            <Text> {this.props.type} </Text>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    if (state.userInputReducer)
        return state.userInputReducer.info;
    return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TypeButton);
```

action.js

```
   export function userInput(info) {
        return {
            type : types.USER_INPUT,
            info
        }
    }
```

reducer.js

I have a create reducer function for the boilerplate code:

```
export const userInputReducer = createReducer(
    {
        info : {
            type : constants.FREE
        }
    },
    {
        [types.USER_INPUT](state, action) {
            let info = action.info;
            if (state.info)
                info = _.assign(state.info, action.info);

            return {
                info
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The problem is that in `mapStateToProps` `this.props.type` has the changed value, but in `customRender` `this.props.type` has the old value and it didn't update. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Note:

If from `mapStateToProps` I return an object that contains type for example:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return state.userInputReducer;
}
```

and replace all over `this.props.type` with `this.props.info.type` everything works fine? I don't really understand what the problem is?

Comment: What do you mean by this?  "The problem is that in mapStateToProps this.props.type has the changed value" . If would help if you could include  of  console.log(state)  in your mapStateToProps, before the click, and after the click.

Comment: The problem was that I was returning the same reference and I was not creating a new object in the reducer.